# Drag and Drop ListView to Listview(Listbox)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, drag-and-drop

I´m writing a little audio player in c#.

Now I want drag and drop some Items from my music library (ListView) to a playlist(ListView or Listbox).

Will this work?

Im using Windows Forms, what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/DragAndDropListView.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work. Just prepare the Playlist control:

```
((Control)PlayList).AllowDrop = true;
PlayList.DragEnter += PlayList_DragEnter;
PlayList.DragDrop += PlayList_DragDrop;
```

And initiate drag from Library ListView:

```
DoDragDrop( new DataObject( DataFormats.FileDrop, paths ), DragDropEffects.Link );
```

(Just modify the parameters as you need)